# Блокировка POST запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, браузер, gecko

Делаю POST запрос с помощью jQuery.post()

```
$.post({
    url: "/drm/add.php",
    data: {script: "yes", id: $('#ID').val(), name: $('#name').val()},
    success: function(data) {
        // if (data == "error") {
            // alert("Введите уникальный id");
        // }
    },
    dataType: "text"
 })
```

Но не получаю ожидаемого действия(add.php должен заносить данные в mysql через pdo), а получаю вот такую информацию в консоли разработчика в браузере Firefox в вкладке "Network" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же сделать Resend запроса через те же инструменты, то все работает.
Запрос не может блокироваться извне (антивирусы, аддоны), я точно в этом уверен, и проверил это.
Никаких запросов на сторонние сервера кроме как для подключения JS библиотек и CSS не используется, субдоменов нет.

Comment: Посмотрите исходный код html который получился. Покажите его. Проверьте, возможно вы перепутали action с method, либо  шлете запрос на другой адрес, чем тот, где опубликован сайт. Возможно ADBlock мешает.

Comment: Возможно имя script не нравится браузеру, попробуйте дать a b c без намёков и аналогично заполнить input-ты, может браузер слово script считает вирусным.

Comment: @nick_n_a изменил параметры и название скрипта до одной буквы (только id две), все так же. Адрес не перепутал. Если переслать через консоль разработчика, то все шлется с кодом 200. ADBlocka нет, проверил даже с пустым браузером.

Comment: Какой именно браузер? Фирма и версия. В других, в фоксе например - тоже самое? (У меня раз был какой-то глюк страшный в фоксе, они за 24 часа исправили).

Comment: @nick_n_a пробовал как в Firefox 80.0.1, так и в Chrome 80.0.3987.149. В первом выводит сообщение о блокировке, которое в содержании вопроса, во втором даже ничего не выводит(и не выполняет). В других браузерах не вижу смысла смотреть.